# Closed and Open Loop gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency, gain, loop-gain

[image: Closed and Open Loop gain]

Please Could you help me to solve this question
I foud hard time for it

---

These what I got
You will find the answer in Page# 1 and Page# 2

[image: Page# 1]

[image: Page# 2]

Comment: You need to show how you attempted it yourself. Unless you want us to give you a partial answer.

Comment: What's the input impedance of the op-amp? With the stated gain it clearly doesn't have 'normal' characteristics.

Comment: The input impedance is 2k ohms

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the op-amp has infinite input impedance, obtain an expression for the voltage, \$\small V^-\$, at the inverting input; then use the TF relationship between \$\small V^-\$ and \$\small V_o\$. This gives a CLTF: \$\small \dfrac{-8}{s+2}\$